# How to insert vertical lines along my scatter plots for specific x-intercept where the values in my variable contains argument "-01-01"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to insert **vertical lines** along the x-axis in my scatter plot. My time series contains observations from 2002-01-01 to 2007-01-12 for variable date.

I want to insert vertical lines along the dates *2002-01-01, 2003-01-01, 2004-01-01, 2005-01-01, 2006-01-01 and 2007-01-01*.

```
ggplot(data)+
   geom_point(aes(y=numdeaths, x=date), colour="blue", alpha="0.3",size=1, position = "jitter")+
   geom_vline(xintercept = grep("-01-01",date))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 p <- ggplot(data) +
        geom_point(
            aes(y = numdeaths, x = date),
            colour = "blue",
            alpha = "0.3",
            size = 1,
            position = "jitter"
        )


for (yr in 2002:2007) {
    p <-
        p + geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date(paste(yr, "01", "01", sep = "/")))
}

p
```